# Android Studio Update Failed Giraffe patch 1 to patch 2

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio More than 3+ years on Different Platforms like Linux (Ubuntu), Windows, While i am using Android Studio their was New Android Studio update From Giraffe Patch 1 to Patch 2, so i decided to update the Android Studio While Updating there was an error message with some message ("Some Conflicts was Found in Installation area")
[image: Error Log]

Comment: Uninstall completely, then have a clean install of the Android Studio

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, close Android Studio IDE, then go to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\resources\app-inspection" on Windows and remove the Read Only property on those two files. Now enter AS IDE again and update to patch 2. (If you don't see the icon, go to Help 'Check for Updates")

After trying many ways this was my work around.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nailed it on Mac too, after write permissions were granted from Read only.

Comment: Yes!! I tried that out the problem is in the permission android studio can't write some properties while updating patch 1 to patch 2 becuase of the "Read inly Permission" - Thankyou

Answer (score 13):

In macOS you need:

1. Open Applications folder
2. Open context menu on "Android Studio.app"
3. Select item "Show package content"
4. Find there files
5. Open context menu on file
6. Change permissions from "read only" to "read and write"
7. Reinstall update

Answer (score 5):

In macOS this is what you need to do:

***First Approach:***
Go to Finder and on the left side click on the "**Applications**" folder. There find **Android Studio Icon** and double-click to open menu options. Now choose the "**show package contents**" option. There you will see a **Contents** folder, open it.

Now follow this path:
**/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/resources/app-inspection**

open *Contents->plugins->android->resources->app-inspection*

Here in **app-inspection** folder, you will see **backgroundtask-inspector.jar** file double-click to open the menu options and click on **Get Info**. Now at the bottom, you will see **Sharing & Permissions** click on it and now change all options from **read only to READ & WRITE**.

Do the same for the **network-inspector.jar** file which you can also find in the app-inspection folder.

Now update your Android studio again.

**Second Approach:**
Uninstall Android Studio and install the latest version from Android's official website.